# BeautifulSoup4 - findAll gets only 10 occurrences

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** some information from website using BeautifulSoup4.
The html looks like this :

```
    <ul class=results__list-container">
       <li class="results__list-container-item">
           <div class="classname1"> attribute1 </div>
           <div class="classname2"> attribute2 </div>
       </li>
       <li class="results__list-container-item">
           <div class="classname1"> attribute1 </div>
           <div class="classname2"> attribute2 </div>
       </li>
       <li class="results__list-container-item">
           <div class="classname1"> attribute1 </div>
           <div class="classname2"> attribute2 </div>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

To get all list elements im using this code :

```
source = requests.get('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
offers_html = soup.find_all("li", {"class": 'results__list-container-item'}, limit=None)
```

By inspecting the html in my browser, i can see that there are 50 occurrences of this class.
It works well on first 10 instances and prints the whole list element with nested classed and i am able to get all needed attributes, but after 10th instance, all i get is just

```html
<li class="results__list-container-item"></li>
```

Is there way to save all the list elements with all nested classes?

Comment: You've confirmed that the HTML contains more than 10 of those elements with children?

Comment: Yes - there are exactly 50 on the website

Comment: How are you getting the HTML?

Comment: using requests and soup :
source = requests.get('https:/xxxxxx').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

Comment: Please do not share code/similar information in the comments, it's difficult to read. You can add it your post, instead.

Comment: You should print the content of soup locally to confirm it matches your expectations as observed in the browser. JavaScript might be loading additional entries on demand.